# keyword-driven test automation framework in Perl

Tags: perl, frameworks

I am looking for a keyword-driven test automation framework in Perl.

We have an embedded device with a GUI (Something like smart phone but no that complex). User can touch anywhere on the UI and do some action. Based on the user click we need to verify whether the respective screen is displayed or not. This is one of the simplest scenario.

I am planning to develop this framework using keyword-driven approach, wherein keys will be these actions and verifications.

I am looking for something like http://fitnesse.org/ in Perl.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few people appear to have started on things in this direction:

[`Test::FITesque`](http://search.cpan.org/~konobi/Test-FITesque-0.03/lib/Test/FITesque.pm)

[`Test::FIT`](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/Test-FIT-0.11/lib/Test/FIT.pm)

[perl-slim](https://github.com/knuthaug/perl-slim)

None of them look mature, but they should give you something to work with if you want to write your own.

Before going down that road, though, I would stop and think whether you *really* want to recreate something like this in Perl.  There are already [good, mature testing tools](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Test-Harness-3.26/lib/TAP/Harness.pm) for Perl that are used by lots of developers.  It may be better to do what you want in a more Perlesque way.  You would not have to do so much reinventing of the wheel.